# Putting percentage labels of a piechart in the legend using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made the following piechart using ggplot2. I was hoping to find a solution where I can have the percentage labels in brackets next to each item in the legend as opposed to on the piechart itself?

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Here is my code below

```
country<-c('Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana')
key<-c('Retail Margin','Wholesale Margin','BFP Component and Related Costs','Customs and Excise Tax','MVA Levy',"Fuel Tax","Petroleum Fund Levy","Road User Charge")
value<-c(0.0687,0.0577,0.7393,0.0031,0.01,0.0126,0.0141,0.0945)
data <-data.frame(country,key,value)

botswana <- ggplot(data, aes("", value, fill = key)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white", size = 1) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = paste0(value * 100, "%")), 
                  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
                  color = "black", size = 4) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  labs(colour = NULL) +
  theme_void()

botswana <- botswana + theme(legend.title = element_blank())
print(botswana)
```

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
country<-c('Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana','Botswana')
key<-c('Retail Margin','Wholesale Margin','BFP Component and Related Costs','Customs and Excise Tax','MVA Levy',"Fuel Tax","Petroleum Fund Levy","Road User Charge")
value<-c(0.0687,0.0577,0.7393,0.0031,0.01,0.0126,0.0141,0.0945)
data <-data.frame(country,key,value)
#Create variable
data$key2 <- paste0(data$key,' [',100*round(data$value,2),'%',']')

botswana <- ggplot(data, aes("", value, fill = key2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white", size = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  labs(colour = NULL) +
  theme_void()

botswana <- botswana + theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]